# Import local STAC catalog to Open Data Cube

Tags: open-data-cube

What's the best way to import my own COGS in an S3 bucket into ODC?

I've currently used both PySTAC and RIO-STAC to generate local catalogs for S3 located tifs.  Both methods produce jsons and the correct hierarchy, but when I try to index using "stac-to-dc" I get an error about not conforming to ITEM_SEARCH. From reading, it looks like this is only supported via a web API which allows a dynamic catalog to be created.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I've read a bunch of posts, but nothing seems to work. I've also looked at the underlying stac_api_to_dc.py library.

FYI:

- S3 access permissions are fine
- Product descriptions have been added to the dc

Answer (score 0):

There's a not-very-well-documented [fs-to-dc](https://github.com/opendatacube/odc-tools/blob/develop/apps/dc_tools/odc/apps/dc_tools/fs_to_dc.py) tool, which you can install with:

`pip install odc-apps-dc-tools`

There's some help provided if you run:

`fs-to-dc --help`

It's goal is basically what you're after, though. Indexing either YAML or STAC from a file system in a simpler way than the regular `datacube` CLI.

Comment: Awesome, Cheers Alex, will take it for a spin now!